# jquery form plugin submit issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form that has an image field in it and I use the jquery form plugin to upload the image via ajax on field change. Here's where my issue comes in. If someone enters an image and it loads it in the form, whenever the form gets submitted again, it uploads the same image again and I can't submit the form normally. It just acts as if I want the jquery form plugin to handle the form submission.

Here is my javascript.

```
<script src="<?php echo DOMAIN.LIBRARY; ?>js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo DOMAIN.LIBRARY; ?>uploader/jcrop/js/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo DOMAIN.LIBRARY; ?>uploader/jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DOMAIN.LIBRARY; ?>uploader/jcrop/css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#fk_profile_form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
      });

    var options = { 
        url:       "<?php echo DOMAIN.LIBRARY; ?>uploader/ajaxUpload.php",         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    }; 

    var $loader = $('<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width: 200px;"><div class="bar" style="width: 100%;">Uploading...</div></div>');
    $(document).on("change", "#photofield", function() {
        $loader.prependTo('#imageArea');
        $('#fk_profile_form').ajaxForm(options).submit();

    });
    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {  

        // dialog function
        var $uploadedImage = $('<img src="<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>'+responseText+'" id="uploadedImage"></img>').appendTo('#imageArea .controls');

        $('<br /><a href="javascript:;" id="removeImage">Click Here To Upload A Different Photo</a>').appendTo('#imageArea .controls');

        $uploadedImage.Jcrop({
            // start off with jcrop-light class
            bgOpacity: 0.5,
            bgColor: 'white',
            addClass: 'jcrop-light',
            allowResize: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            setSelect: [0,0,300,300],
            minSize: [300,300],
            onSelect: updateCoords
        });

        $loader.remove();
        $('#ajaxImageUpload').show();
        $('#photofield').next('span').hide();
        $('#photofield').hide();

    } 

    function updateCoords(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };

    function checkCoords()
    {
        if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
        alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
        return false;
    };

    $(document).on("click", "#removeImage", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.jcrop-holder').remove();
        $('#photofield').show();
        $('#photofield').next('span').show();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#photofield').val('');

    });

    $('#sc').on('click', function() {

        alert($('#x').val()+','+$('#y').val()+','+$('#w').val()+','+$('#h').val());

    });

    $(".other_option").each(function(i) {

        if($(this).val() != 'other') {

            $(this).next('input').hide();

        } else {

            $(this).next('input').show();

        }

    });

    $(document).on("change", "select[name=question[]]", function() {

        if($(this).val() == 'other') {

            $(this).next("input").show();

        } else {

            $(this).next("input").hide();

        }

    });

    $(document).on("change", "input:checkbox[name=fk_rainbow_bridge]", function() {

        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('#fk_dob').show();

        } else {

            $('#fk_dob').hide();

        }

    });

    function checkField(field, value) {

        $.post("<?php echo DOMAIN.INCLUDES; ?>ajax/profileForm.php", { fieldName: field, fieldValue: value },
        function(data){
            if(data) {

                $('input[name='+field+'], select[name='+field+'], textarea[name='+field+']').next('span').text(data);
                $('#'+field).removeClass('success').addClass('error');

            } else {

                $('input[name='+field+'], select[name='+field+'], textarea[name='+field+']').next('span').empty();
                $('#'+field).removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            }

        });

    }


    $(document).on("focusout", "input[name=fk_name]", function(){

        checkField('fk_name', $(this).val());

    });

    $(document).on("focusout", "input[name=fk_breed]", function(){

        checkField('fk_breed', $(this).val());

    });

    $(document).on("focusout", "select[name=fk_gender]", function(){

        checkField('fk_gender', $(this).val());

    });

    $(document).on("focusout", "select[name=fk_dob_month]", function(){

        checkField('fk_dob_month', $(this).val());

    });

    $(document).on("focusout", "textarea[name=fk_about]", function(){

        checkField('fk_about', $(this).val());

    });

});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When posting some data to your server you should be very careful about the parameters you supply @ your request. If you are hitting the same server path with the same parameters, then your browser will cache the response (by default) and will populate your first response that had the same request parameters.. I my self am using sth like the following to ensure that each request will be unique.. and no caching will be applied..

```
$.post("<your server path url>",
{
    random_number: Math.random()
});
```